# Precompile all the assets without having to add them to app-ion.css/js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I precompile all css, js and **images** (**and in subdirectories also**) under my_app/app/assets without having to add some of them (that I don't want to) to application.css/js? Is it just rake asset:precompile:all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the images will be precompiler by running the default task.

If you want to precompile all the js and css, you can add this to your `initializers/assest.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += [Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/assets/javascripts/**/*"].reject { |fn| File.directory?(fn) }]
config.assets.precompile += [Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/**/*"].reject { |fn| File.directory?(fn) }]
```

Comment: what about my another question?

Comment: `rake asset:precompile:all` will not solve your problem, it will only compile the images, and the css and js, which are includes in application.js(.css), if you haven't added anything to the procompile array

Comment: rake asset:precompile:all doesn't exist

Comment: `rake assets:precompile:all` exists ;)

Comment: added the info how to require all the nested directories. But images should be already compilated, including the nested folders

Comment: rake -T ---> rake assets:precompile:all doesn't exist.

Comment: then it's just `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: why did you include `[Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/*"]` (images) if you just said that all images are added automatically?